# Taglib# Portable does not save modified tags

Tags: c#, audio, save, mp3, taglib

I am trying to edit some tags within a Mp3-File with [taglib# portable](https://github.com/timheuer/taglib-sharp-portable). Here is my code:

```
using System;
using TagLib;

namespace SharedCode {
public class MP3File : AudioFile {

    public enum AvailableTags {
        Artist,
        Title,
        AlbumName,
        AmazonID,
        BeatsPerMinute,
        Comment,
        Genre,
        Year,
        Key
    }

    public MP3File (String path) : base (path) {

    }

    public override String ToString () {
        return this.Filename + " | " + this.getValue (AvailableTags.Artist) + " | " + this.getValue (AvailableTags.Title);
    }

    public void setValue (AvailableTags tag, String value) {

        //TagLib.File theFile = TagLib.File.Create (abstractionFile, ReadStyle.None);

        //StreamFileAbstraction s = new StreamFileAbstraction (this.Filename, this.Stream, this.Stream);
        //TagLib.File theFile = TagLib.File.Create (s, ReadStyle.None);

        AudioFileAbstraction abstractionFile = new AudioFileAbstraction (this);

        using(TagLib.File theFile = TagLib.File.Create(abstractionFile, ReadStyle.None)){

            if (tag == AvailableTags.Artist) {
                theFile.Tag.Composers = new string[1]{ value };
            } else if (tag == AvailableTags.Title) {
                theFile.Tag.Title = value;
            } else if (tag == AvailableTags.AlbumName) {
                theFile.Tag.Album = value;
            } else if (tag == AvailableTags.AmazonID) {
                theFile.Tag.AmazonId = value;
            } else if (tag == AvailableTags.BeatsPerMinute) {
                theFile.Tag.BeatsPerMinute = uint.Parse (value);
            } else if (tag.Equals (AvailableTags.Comment)) {
                theFile.Tag.Comment = value;
            } else if (tag.Equals (AvailableTags.Genre)) {
                theFile.Tag.Genres [0] = value;
            } else if (tag == AvailableTags.Year) {
                theFile.Tag.Year = uint.Parse (value);
            }

            theFile.Save ();
            //theFile.Dispose ();
        }
    }

    public String getValue (AvailableTags tag) {
        //AudioFileAbstraction abstractionFile = new AudioFileAbstraction (this);
        //TagLib.File theFile = TagLib.File.Create (abstractionFile, ReadStyle.None);

        String returnValue = "";

        StreamFileAbstraction s = new StreamFileAbstraction (this.Filename, this.Stream, this.Stream);
        TagLib.File theFile = TagLib.File.Create (s, ReadStyle.Average);

        if (tag == AvailableTags.Artist) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.Composers [0];
        } else if (tag == AvailableTags.Title) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.Title;
        } else if (tag == AvailableTags.AlbumName) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.Album;
        } else if (tag == AvailableTags.AmazonID) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.AmazonId;
        } else if (tag == AvailableTags.BeatsPerMinute) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.BeatsPerMinute.ToString ();
        } else if (tag.Equals (AvailableTags.Comment)) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.Comment;
        } else if (tag.Equals (AvailableTags.Genre)) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.Genres [0];
        } else if (tag == AvailableTags.Year) {
            returnValue = theFile.Tag.Year.ToString ();
        } else if (tag == AvailableTags.Key) {
            //return theFile.Tag.Artists [0];
        }

        theFile.Dispose ();

        return returnValue;
    }
}
}


// Test call
        MP3File af = new MP3File(@"/Users/danielmartin/Desktop/test.mp3");
        af.setValue (MP3File.AvailableTags.Title, "DFies ist ein Test");
        Logger.output (af.getValue(MP3File.AvailableTags.Title));
```

If i call the setValue()-Method, my program does not crash or outputs anything, it just runs through, but the Tags were not saved.

I am working on a OS X Machine and the file definitely exists

Please help me

Comment: Are you missing a `MP3File.Save();` ?

Comment: MP3File is a class implemented by me, so, no, nowhere in the web is described, that there is an other save process

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007298/taglib-not-saving-id3-tag?rq=1)?

Comment: i stumbled over this Thread, but could not do anything with it, especially it was written in C++